# How to figure out which Instagram user has deauthorized your app with deauthorization callback url

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have followed the procedure at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

The last step of step2 is the deauthorization callback;

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started#deauthorize-callback-url

When I enter a callback url for it, it does call my endpoint correctly, however it's just an HTTP POST and does not contain any body or query parameters or anything I can use to figure out which user deauthorized. I think I'm missing something here.

The instructions guide you to this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#parsingsr

But again the HTTP POST still does not give me that `signed_request`.
My app is still `in development` status on the dashboard. This may be the problem but I don't think it is or should be because I should be able to test without releasing.
Please let me know if you know how to figure out the user who deauthorized your app.
Thanks!

Comment: @nezvo How did you trigger deauthorization? Apps and Websites section of Instagram does have only one button, which is "remove" and it's triggering any callbacks

Comment: deletion-callback-url calling then user removes application but as you said we can't make sure that passed signed_request parameter is related to which user! Facebook documented 
 it so bad.

Comment: Did you find out how to get user_id from a deauth callback ?
Request body only contains a short buffer that contains a signature.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem. When I test it in local, no problem, I have got the signed_request parameter in body but when I try on a server, body is empty.

Comment: I think I found the problem : https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1485832065259000/?join_id=f290dd8c434813c